# What is the epslatex tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

What is the [epslatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epslatex) tag? I was under the impression that [`epslatex`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) is just a document (*i.e.*, not a package) describing how images and graphics have worked in (La)TeX in the past and present, but is there something else that `epslatex` refers to? If not, should the [epslatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epslatex) tag just be merged (or made a synonym of) the [eps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eps) tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epslatex

shows that the questions tagged [epslatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epslatex) are about gnuplot's epslatex output (which generates an EPS file with a tex fragment with a picture environment overlaying latex typeset text).

So I just edited the tag wiki to say that is what the tag is for....

https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/epslatex/info

Comment: Fair enough ... haha.